# Converting Docbook 5.0 (with partial includes) to PDF

Tags: xml, xerces, docbook, xinclude

I was trying to convert a docbook document with fragmented/partial includes to pdf using Xerces 2.7.1 and Xalan 2.7.0.

```
<xi:include href="./TestDocument.included.xml" xpointer="Section2"/>
```

This did not work until I figured out that in order to use partial includes one has to provide a resolveable path to the schemafile using `<!DOCTYPE ..>`.

But with Docbook 5.0 one should/has to use namespace declarations instead of DOCTYPE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
xml:lang="de" version="5.0" status="DRAFT" security="confidential">
```

How can I provide the docbookxi.rng to the toolchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "provide the docbookxi.rng to the toolchain" that would help in this case. There isn't even a standard way to associate an XML document with a RELAX NG schema. The `xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"` namespace declaration identifies the document as DocBook 5 (together with the `version` attribute), but it does not say anything about the location of the schema.

A line like this one,

```
<xi:include href="./TestDocument.included.xml" xpointer="Section2"/>
```

means: "include the portion of `TestDocument.included.xml` that is identified by the element that has an attribute of type ID with a value of `Section2`".

In DocBook 5, `xml:id` is used for unique identifiers. This attribute is recognized as being of type ID, and there is no need for a schema to determine its "ID-ness" (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/). So if you have any`id` attributes in your DocBook 5 documents, change them to `xml:id`.

Howewer, you should also make sure that the XML parser supports `xml:id`. Xerces seems to be lacking here, so it might still not work for you (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-1113).

If there are problems, you could try to use the [DocBook 5 DTD](http://www.docbook.org/xml/5.0/dtd/docbook.dtd) (yes, there is a DTD even though the normative schema is written in RELAX NG). That DTD declares `xml:id` to be of type ID.

Comment: How exactly do I "use" the Docbook DTD?

Comment: Download the DTD and add a DOCTYPE declaration to the XML document. Like this: `<!DOCTYPE book SYSTEM "docbook.dtd">` (assuming here that the XML file and the DTD are in the same directory). You did mention `<!DOCTYPE ..>` in the question so I assumed that you knew already.